# What is the equivalent of JSP's c:set in a Ruby on Rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsp, variables, view, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.  What is the equivalent of JSP's c:set in a Rails view?  In JSP you can set a page variable like so

```
<c:set var="myVar" value="myValue" />
```

How do I do that in a Rails view?   Note that I'm invoking this logic from within a loop in my Rails view so each iteration could set the variable to something else.  As such, I do not want any logic in my controller, only in my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical Rails app uses ERB. This can look like:

```
<%- myVar = myValue %>
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html#templates-partials-and-layouts